# Iterating over dynamically generated controls and getting certain properties

Tags: silverlight, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl that has an ItemsControl. This ItemsControl is bound to a list of objects. To display those objects, I have **DataTemplate**s that determine how the object is presented.

I want to be able to retrieve the current values of the controls, such as Text if it is a TextBox, or SelectedItem if it is a ComboBox.

How do I iterate over these dynamically generated controls? I do not know the names of the controls, as they are generated during runtime.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest why I could think of besides searching the visual tree for the controls and theirs template properties is probably to bind the ItemsControl data source to an ObservableCollection. This why you can dynamically add any type of controls to the list.

Once you do that, you can easily check the type of each UIElement within the list. e.g; if it's a Textbox then get the text property by casting, etc.

Comment: Yes, actually I have bound the ItemsControl source to a List.. I think that's still an ObservableCollection right? How do I check the UIElement in the ItemsControl list? ItemsControl.Items only gives me the list source.. It doesn't give me the controls that are in the ItemsControl..

Comment: First, the reason why I suggested ObservableCollection is that ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface, so when items in the list are changed (remove/add), it will update whichever element you bind the list to. Normally, you can cast the ItemsControl.datasource or even ItemsControl.items (i'm not sure at the top of my head) to whichever element type it is. However, I would suggest you to work with the actual list element that you set the binding to. This way, it follow the MVVM design pattern and will make your life a lot easier when building a more complex app.

Comment: Hmm.. That makes sense.. However I'm not sure how to adapt it to what I have so far. I have a list of objects that basically just tell my control how to present a user interface.. For example, I have an object that has a displayname member, and a list of strings (choices) to display. The user control displays this as a combo box. This object has no field for setting the selected item. If it did, i still wouldn't know how I could bind the selected item to it.. :S Hoo boy this is so confusing :S

Comment: If you were to follow the MVVM design pattern, then you should create a subclass of the ObservableCollection and implement a way to keep  track of the selected item. Once you have done that, bind to the ItemControl SelectedItemChanged event to get called every time the selected item changes.Inside the handler for the selecteditemchanged, set the new selected item as the selected item in your custom subclass list object (casting your sender.itemsource).

Comment: I think I might not have explained clearly. I want to get the selected item of the dynamically generated combo box inside the ItemsControl, not the selected item of the ItemsControl itself.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: When dynamically generating your combobox, hook the new combobox "selecteditemchanged" event to a handler, so that whenever that dynamically generated combobox selected item changed, the handler will get invoked. (assuming i understood you correctly).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have found a way to get the elements (comboboxes, textboxes) by using VisualTreeHelper and getting the type of the framework element.. :)